# How to pass an argument to dialogFragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, android-dialogfragment

How can I pass values to dialog fragment?

Let's say I've `isStarted` bool value, and I pass this argument to `DialogFragment` like this:

```
DatePickerFragmentDialog(isStarted).show
```

And inside my `DialogFragment` I get the argument:

```
class DatePickerFragmentDialog(isStarted: Boolean) : DialogFragment() {

override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {}
}
```

But I can't use this argumnet in the `onCreateDialog` override method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use arguments to pass your values:

```
class DatePickerFragmentDialog : DialogFragment() {

    companion object {
        fun newInstance(isStarted: Boolean): DatePickerFragmentDialog {
            val f = DatePickerFragmentDialog()
            // Supply isStarted input as an argument.
            val args = Bundle()
            args.putBoolean("isStarted", isStarted)
            f.arguments = args
            return f
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
        val isStarted = arguments?.getBoolean("isStarted")
        // Return some dialog
        return super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState)
    }
}
```

Show it:

```
val fragment = DatePickerFragmentDialog.newInstance(true)
fragment.show(supportFragmentManager, "myFragment")
```